# If a strictly convex function attains a minimum on the unit ball, does it attain a minimum on every weak*-compact set?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X'$ be the topological dual of a normed TVS $X$, and let $f$ be a real, strictly convex function on $X'$

> If $f$ attains a minimum on the closed unit ball of $X'$, does it attain a minimum on every weak*-compact subset of $X'$?

---

**Attempt.** My guess is that it's not true.

Let $X = X' = \mathbb R$, so that the closed unit ball in $X'$ is $[1,-1]$. The idea now is to define $f$ so that it's continuous on $[-1,1]$, and therefore achieves a minimum, but introduce a discontinuity elsewhere so that it doesn't achieve a minimum on some other closed interval.

For example, I was thinking something like $f(x) = (x-2)^2$ if $x \in (-\infty,2)$ and $f(x)$ is a linear on $[2,\infty)$ with, say, $f(2)=1$. Then $f$ doesn't attain a minimum on $[1,2]$.

I'm not sure I can define $f$ in a way that makes it strictly convex, however. (Turns out I can't. See diracdeltafunk's comment below.)

Comment: Thanks for adressing this. I deleted my previous comment because it is no longer relevant.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but what does "the closed unit ball of $X'$" mean if $X$ is just a topological vector space? Where is the norm on $X'$ coming from?

Comment: As a side note, the claim is true if $X = \mathbb{R}$. Then $X'$ with the weak* topology is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with the norm topology, and a convex function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is always continuous. A continuous function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ always attains a minimum on a compact set.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Changed to "normed TVS", thanks